# Eq => function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am trying to figure out how to write this function with the Eq function in Haskell.

An easy function that I am trying to implement is:

```
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
```

Where f will gather each repeated consecutive elements under separate sub-lists, For example:

```
f [3] = [[3]]
f [1,1,1,3,2,2,1,1,1,1] = [[1,1,1],[3],[2,2],[1,1,1,1]]
```

I thought about this function:

```
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
f [] = []
f (x:[]) = [[x]]
f (x:x':xs) = if x == x' then [[x, x']] ++ (f (xs))
                    else [[x]] ++ (bundler (xs))
```

It seems to not work well since when it arrives to the last element, it wants to compare it to its consecutive, which clearly does not exist.

Moreover, I feel like I do not use anything with the Eq => function.

I would like to receive an answer that will show how to use Eq properly in my case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I feel like I do not use anything with the Eq => function." You're using `==`, which is defined in the `Eq` typeclass. If you didn't have the `Eq` constraint, you couldn't use `==`. So you *are* using `Eq` properly.

Comment: So when I use Eq it lets me use ==, same for + , - etc ?

Comment: `+` and `-` are defined in `Num`.

Comment: A typeclass is a collection of function names (and their types). The `Eq` class provides the `==` function name. An instance of a typeclass is an implementation of those named functions for a specific type. So when you say `Eq a => [a]`, what you are saying is "Lists whose element type has a defined `==` function". When you say `Num a => a`, what you are saying is "a type that has implemented `+` and `*` and the other functions of `Num`.

Comment: `Eq` is used only for `Eq`uality. If you want to treat something like a `Num`ber, use `Num` (in certain cases). If you want to see information about a typeclass, type `:info <class>` in GHCi, for instance `:info Eq`.

Comment: Thank you all. Can someone please show it over my function and tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your problem is not related to the `Eq` typeclass. You could see this by changing its type to use a concrete type that implements `Eq`, for example `f :: [Int] -> [[Int]]`. You will still have the same problem, and there is no `Eq` around.

Answer (score 4):

The presence of the `Eq` typeclass in your type is a red herring: it is not related to the error you report. The error you report happens because you have defined how the function should behave when the list is empty (`f [] =`) and when the list has at least two elements (`f (x:x':xs) =`), but not when the list has exactly one element. The solution will be to add a case that begins*

```
f [x] = ????
```

and decide how to deal with one-element lists. Or to find some other way to write the function that deals with all of its cases.

---

* Note that `f [x]` is the same thing as `f (x:[])`.

Comment: I would have to see the new code in context along with an error message to know why it doesn't compile. But the good news is that you now have a new problem to solve, and that is progress! (OP had reported that adding `f[x]=[[x]]` gave an error.)

Comment: Thank you, let me edit my question so you can see the current code

Comment: Please don't edit questions into different questions. This will make all of the current work irrelevant and confuse people who may see it later. Please post a new question.

Comment: Sure, I just added a new line thats it. The question stayed the same. Should I still open a new question for that ?

Comment: No, that's ok. In response to your edit, `f x:[]` is not the same thing as `f [x]` or `f (x:[])` and will not work.

Comment: (The parens are required here.)

Comment: Added parentheses, it compiles but still do not considers the last element. Also, for [1,1,1,2] it will output [[1,1],[1]] :(

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`span`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:span) and a recursive call to make it work:

```
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
f [] = []
f l@(x:xs) = grouped : f remainder
    where
        (grouped, remainder) = span (== x) l
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/CheerfulStupidTrigger)