# Haskell beginners level function implementation

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am new to Haskell and am trying to write quite an easy function which gathers each repeated consecutive elements under separate sub-lists, For example:

```
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
```

So:

```
f [] = []
f [3] = [[3]]
f [1,1,1,3,2,2,1,1,1,1] = [[1,1,1],[3],[2,2],[1,1,1,1]]
```

I thought about this function:

```
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
f [] = []
f (x:[]) = [[x]]
f (x:x':xs) = if x == x' then [[x, x']] ++ (f (xs))
                    else [[x]] ++ (f (xs))
```

It seems to not work well since when it arrives to the last element, it wants to compare it to its consecutive, which clearly does not exist.

I would like to receive a simple answer (beginner level) that will **not** be too different than mine, correcting my code will be the best.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the standard [`group`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group) function, which does exactly this.

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55580150/1126841)?

Comment: Chepner is right; this is almost exactly the same as your previous question. **Do not post a question twice.**

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't really what you said, it's just that you only hard-coded the cases that either one or two consecutive elements are equal. Actually you want to ground together *an arbitrary* number of equal consecutives. IOW, for every element, you pop off as many following ones as are equal.

Generally, splitting of the head-part of a list which fulfills some condition is what the [`span`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:span) function does. In this case, the condition it's supposed to check is *being equal to the element you already removed*. That's written thus:

```
f [] = []
f (x:xs) = (x:xCopies) : f others
 where (xCopies,others) = span (==x) xs
```

Here, `x:xCopies` puts together the chunk of elements equal to `x` (with `x` itself on front), use that as the heading chunk-list of the result, and then you recurse over all the elements that remain.

Comment: Thank you. Is there another way to write it so it'll look closer to what I did? for example without span and where

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that both halves of your `if` have the same structure: they cons exactly one element onto the front of the recursive call. This can't be right: sometimes you want to add an element to the front of the list, and other times you want to combine your element with what's already in the recursive call.

Instead, you need to pattern-match on the recursive call to get the first item in the recursive result, and then prepend to *that* when the first two items match.

```
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
f [] = []
f [x] = [[x]]
f (x:xs@(y:_)) | x == y = (x:head):more
               | otherwise = [x]:result
  where result@(head:more) = f xs
```